# How to sort a list of QWidgets in QScrollArea

Tags: c++, list, qt, sorting, qwidget

I have a number of rows with images, text, and a bunch of data. Each row is a separate `QWidget`. Each has a unique number assigned to it (input by user, used `setObjectName("rzad_"+number)` ). What I need to do is sort the rows in descending order every time a new is added.

How can I do that?

edit:
I've tried a global `QListWidget`, but it crashes when retrieving the widget. Right after adding the `QWidget` to the `QListWidget`, I can do this:

```
ui->scrollAreaWidgetContentsZdjeciaButow->layout()->addWidget(listaWidget->findChild<QWidget*>("rzadKontener_" + poziom));
```

It will add the widget to the area, but after that, when I call sortRows method,

```
std::sort(poziomyNachylenia.begin(), poziomyNachylenia.end(), std::greater<int>());

QWidget* nowyZestawRzedow = new QWidget; //new widget for sorted rows
QVBoxLayout* nowyZestawRzedowLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
nowyZestawRzedowLayout->setContentsMargins(-5, -5, -5, -5);
nowyZestawRzedowLayout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft);
nowyZestawRzedowLayout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop);
nowyZestawRzedow->setLayout(nowyZestawRzedowLayout);

qDebug() << ui->scrollAreaWidgetContentsZdjeciaButow->layout()->count() << "count";

for (int i = 0; i < ui->scrollAreaWidgetContentsZdjeciaButow->layout()->count(); ++i) {
    QString numerRzedu = QString::number(poziomyNachylenia[i]);

    //this crashes the app
    nowyZestawRzedow->layout()->addWidget(listaWidget->findChild<QWidget*>("rzadKontener_" + numerRzedu)); 
    //and so does this.
    QString nameT = listaWidget->findChild<QWidget*>("rzadKontener_" + numerRzedu)->objectName();  
    qDebug() << "added" << nameT;
}
```

What gives?

Comment: Can't you just use `QListWidget` (perhaps with custom widgets as items, see `QListWidget::setItemWidget`)?

Comment: @Rostislav tried, retrieving the widget in sorting method crashes the app

Comment: That's not how you use a `QListWidget`! If you use `setItemWidget`, then the list widget manages the widgets and **they cannot be in a layout**. Sorting a list widget is a trivial matter, you must be doing something wrong but you don't show the code.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. I completly missed the point of `ListWidget`. It works now, figured it out a couple of hours ago. What I did was `setText(elevationLevel)` to each item that corresponds with the "elevation level" user needs to input, and I simply call `->sortItems(Qt::DescendingOrder)`. Works wonderfully. Now I have a new problem - when the user wants to change the elevation level manually (via `LineEdit`), how can I also change the order of items in `QListWidget`? If I do `takeItem` and/or `setText(newLevel)`, the custom QWidget with all the pictures and buttons disappears.